# Similar questions pane doesn't scroll properly when drafting a question

Tags: bug, design, similar-questions

> [image: screenshot of similar questions pane showing overlapping text]

On a Mac in Firefox 80.0.1, when I scroll the similar questions pane, the initial text visible in the pane doesn't scroll; the questions scroll under it. If I leave the page (like to post this question on Meta) and return, it resolves itself until new content is added to the pane when I continue typing a title. I initially noticed it on another site, but was able to reproduce it here on Meta as I was typing this question.

I've tried shifting the focus between the body, title and the similar questions pane, but the only thing that has worked to "fix" it is to leave the page and come back. It seems like some event handler is missing a step?

Comment: Thanks for finding the dupe @Luuklag - I looked for one but didn't find that one because I was searching for different key words.